# Woocommerce - create user after payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a membership site made I wp/woocommerce

Right now a new user is created when checkout is complete but before payment i complete

Payment (quickpay) happens on a separate site after checkout.

Is there a way to "move" user creation to the thank-you page after payment is complete. So the user doesn't get username/password until after they have paid

Answer (score 0):

Hello it is possible to redirect to thankyou page after doing 3rd party payment from different website and then redirect it. Please refer below url.

https://nicola.blog/2015/01/21/customize-the-thank-you-page-in-woocommerce/

Note: Please Dont Forget to add thankyou page from backend in woocommerce settings.

Comment: Hi Karan

Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't change the user creation process - or i'm I missing something? 

The problem is that the customer gets the username/password before they have paid

Comment: Can you please tell me which membership plugin are you using ?

Comment: Woocommece subscription (https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/)

Comment: Hello Morten Samson Please Review this link below

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions-handles-staging-sites/